# Cannot identify what this "2" is in pandas dataframe header?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am writing a script to format data from an excel sheet template I frequently use so that I can work with it without having to manually format it each time. I am using the following code to remove some useless header rows that appear and make the third row the actual header.

```
new_header = df.iloc[2] #grab the third row for the header
df = df[3:] #take the data below the new header row
df.columns = new_header #set the header row as the df header
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

This works great except when I view the dataframe there is a 2 above my index. This does not appear to be the index name or a column name (I have checked both) and there does not appear to be multiindexing present. This seems rather simple but I am stumped as to what this 2 is and how I can remove it.

[image: Image of the DataFrame]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your input dataframe.

Comment: This may be an XY problem - are you reading the file with `read_excel` and if so have you tried using `skiprows` and `header`?

Comment: Otherwise, `new_header = df.iloc[2].values`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the result of your `new_header`  when you pull the third row  `df.iloc[2]`. You will notice that it has the index `2` in the output. That is where it comes from. You can git rid of it by changing the first line to `new_header = df.iloc[2].to_list()`

Comment: I tried checking the new_header output prior but did not realize it was named '2' and was merely checking the output values. This solved it, thank you!

Comment: have been there, you are welcome! :)